# load files into docker volumes from host using YAML file -docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have build a `wordpress` with `wordpress cli` image by using `Docker Compose`. It was working great. Now I want install `plugins` in it. 
I have my `plugin zip` file in the directory where the `docker_compose.yml` file is placed. I want to add lines in my `docker compose` file to install the plugin and load it in the Docker Container.

Here's the yml file i wrote:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: paulsteven
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: paulsteven
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: passw
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: "wp_"
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./wp_plugins_files: /var/www/html       ==>  here it is,but it does not loaded and installed in container
  wordpress-cli:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wordpress
    image: wordpress:cli
    user: xfs
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c '
      sleep 10;
      wp core install --path="/var/www/html" --url="http://192.168.1.34:8000" --title="Local Wordpress By Docker" --admin_user=paulsteven --admin_password=pass --admin_email=paulsteven@mail.com;
      wp plugin install gutenberg.1.9.1.zip –activate    ==> Install plugin in Container
      '

    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html

volumes:
  db_data:
  wp_data:
```

But my file didn't get loaded in container. I don't know how to make it possible. I want the container with my plugin file installed.  Help me with Some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Solution regarding your code:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpressdb
      MYSQL_USER: paulsteven
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passw

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: paulsteven
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: passw
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: "wp_"
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1

    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./wp_plugins:/var/www/html/wp_plugins
  wordpress-cli:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - wordpress
    image: wordpress:cli

    user: xfs

    command: >
      /bin/sh -c '
      sleep 10;
      wp core install --path="/var/www/html" --url="http://192.168.1.34:8000" --title="Local Wordpress By Docker" --admin_user=paulsteven --admin_password=passw --admin_email=paulstevens@mail.com;
      wp plugin install /var/www/html/wp_plugins/plugin_name.zip;
      wp plugin activate plugin_name'

    volumes:
      - wp_data:/var/www/html
      - ./wp_plugins:/var/www/html/wp_plugins      
volumes:
  db_data:
```